# Pull from array which is in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which contains a teams array and that contains a players array.

I would like to delete from the players array.
I think I know hot to delete from an array, but I can't make it work.
There was a case when it deleted all elements from the teams array.

Here it is how the doc look like:

```
"teams" : [
  {
   "_guid" : "5c5b3bc0-a957-11e5-b909-b7a1cbe2c8be", 
   "teamname" : "Ping-Win_team", 
   "_id" : ObjectId("567a68f6a7c726540b2d746b"), 
   "players" : [
         ObjectId("567a68f6a7c726540b2d7469"), 
         ObjectId("567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c")
        ]
    }
],
```

**My probation:**

```
db.lobbies.update({ _id: ObjectId('567a68f6a7c726540b2d746a') }, { $pull: { 'teams': { 'players.$': ObjectId('567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c')  }}})
```

Thanks for helping,
Akos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to change the `name` field. The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.lobbies.update(
    { "teams.players": ObjectId("567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c") },
    {
        "$pull": {
            "teams.$.players": ObjectId("567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c")
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works correctly!
But could you explain please why did you change to where clause to find by teams.players instead of the parent doc _id? I'm just curious, thanks :)

Comment: @Akos Since the positional **`$`** operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, the array field must appear as part of the query document hence you need the `teams` array field in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to delete one or multiple values in a nested array

```
db.sessions.update(
    { 
         "teams": {
           $elemMatch: {
                "players": {$in: [ObjectId("567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c")]}
         }
    }},
    {
        "$pull": {
            "teams.$.players": {$in:[ObjectId("567a68f7a7c726540b2d746c")]}
         }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got correctly your question.. you can't pull one of the player IDs because:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

From: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/

Otherwise you will pull the whole item of the teams array that contains that specific player.